# Calling methods on Vis.js react network graph

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

I'm trying to call a few methods from network graph, such as getConnectedNodes() but I'm getting null or undefined error.

I have a graph element defined like so

```
<Graph ref={this.networkRef} graph={graph} options={options} events={events} style={{ height: "640px" }} />
```

My constructor has a ref definition

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {}
        this.networkRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

and when I try and call

```
const events = {

    hoverNode:function(event){
     console.log(this.networkRef.current.Network.getConnectedNodes())

    }
};
```

I get undefined error. I've Tried printing just this.networkRef still undefined.

When I put console.log(this.networkRef) in the render function it show  object with null value but when I open it it has data.

Any thoughts on how to call vis.js network graph methods in react.js and as part of hover event function shown above.

Comment: first this I would check is the proper installation of the module and the proper import into your React file.

Comment: I have imported vis.js as such ```import Graph from "react-graph-vis";``` and the packaged is installed. Anyone any thoughts on how to call network graph methods in reactjs?

Comment: I think you have to include it as an React element in the render statement like
return(){
<Graph graph={your graph info here} options={your options info here} events={your eventHandling here}  />
}

Comment: I have added methods in the Graph element but how would I call it? How would I use reference? Has anyone got an example?
```
<Graph ref={this.networkRef} graph={graph} options={options} events={events} style={{ height: "640px" }} /> 
```

Comment: have you checked in the module whether these functions are exported?